# No implicit upcasting with function pointers arguments?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, contravariance, upcasting

This is kind of a strange situation I've run into. I expected for the pointer to be implicitly upcast:

```
struct BaseClass
{};

struct DerivedClass : BaseClass
{};

void baseClassArgFunc(BaseClass* arg) {}            // Function taking BaseClass argument
void derivedClassArgFunc(DerivedClass* arg) {}      // Function taking DerivedClass argument

int main()
{
    void (*pBaseFuncArg) (BaseClass*);      // Pointer to function taking BaseClass argument
    void (*pDerivedFuncArg) (DerivedClass*);    // Pointer to function taking DerivedClass argument

    pBaseFuncArg = baseClassArgFunc;            // Assign pointer, works fine
    pDerivedFuncArg = derivedClassArgFunc;      // Assign pointer, works fine

    pBaseFuncArg = derivedClassArgFunc;         // A value of type void (*) (DerivedClass *arg) cannot be 
                                                // assigned to an entity of type void (*) (BaseClass *)

    pDerivedFuncArg = baseClassArgFunc;         // A value of type void (*) (BaseClass *arg) cannot be 
                                                // assigned to an entity of type void (*) (DerivedClass *)

    return 0;
}
```

I expected assigning void ( * ) (DerivedClass*) to void baseClassArgFunc(BaseClass* arg) to be safe. I'm confused. I guess there's no implicit upcasting with function pointer arguments then?

Comment: **Yes**. No implicit upcasting here.

Comment: Correct. Not sure this question can really get an answer beyond "yes". Are you looking for anything more than that?

Comment: @hvd: Something like `compatible_cast<>` for function-pointers, member-pointers and member-function-pointers would be nice...

Comment: @hvd Hmm, yes I guess so, I'm not sure whether what I was expecting was reasonable, the language has got so many ins and outs I'm not sure what to expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing your classes to expose the issues:

```
struct BaseClass
{
};

struct DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    int a;
};
```

Then

```
pBaseFuncArg = derivedClassArgFunc;
```

is unsafe for:

```
 void derivedClassArgFunc(DerivedClass* arg) { arg->a = 42; }


 int main()
 {
     void (*pBaseFuncArg) (BaseClass*) = derivedClassArgFunc;
     BaseClass base;

     //derivedClassArgFunc(&base); // Doesn't compile as expected
     pBaseFuncArg(&base);          // Would be UB, base->i won't exist
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to think of which way would be safe or unsafe. I think the other way is safe, but it seems there's just no implicit casting here.